# xsi:type issue when deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml

Please forgive me for not being well-versed in XML declaration and what must be done from a class and definition perspective to make serialization/deserialization work.  I'm attempting to deserialize the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AccessControlPolicy xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <Owner>
      <ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID>
   </Owner>
   <AccessControlList>
      <Grant>
         <Grantee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CanonicalUser">
            <ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID>
         </Grantee>
         <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
      </Grant> 
   </AccessControlList>
</AccessControlPolicy>
```

Throws the following exception:

```
The specified type was not recognized: name='CanonicalUser', namespace='http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/', at <Grantee xmlns='http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/'>.
```

I reduced the code to the following to reproduce in isolation:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Xml.Serialization; 

namespace sandbox
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<AccessControlPolicy xmlns=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/\"><Owner><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Owner><AccessControlList><Grant><Grantee xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Grantee><Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission></Grant><Grant><Grantee xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Grantee><Permission>READ</Permission></Grant><Grant><Grantee xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Grantee><Permission>WRITE</Permission></Grant><Grant><Grantee xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Grantee><Permission>READ_ACP</Permission></Grant><Grant><Grantee xsi:type=\"CanonicalUser\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><ID>946a0786-3840-4007-afe1-76f138a3d31c</ID></Grantee><Permission>WRITE_ACP</Permission></Grant></AccessControlList></AccessControlPolicy>";

            try
            {
                AccessControlPolicy acp = DeserializeXml<AccessControlPolicy>(xml);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static T DeserializeXml<T>(string xml)
        { 
            XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                return (T)xmls.Deserialize(ms);
            } 
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AccessControlPolicy", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class AccessControlPolicy
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Owner", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public Owner Owner { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccessControlList", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public AccessControlList AccessControlList { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AccessControlList", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class AccessControlList
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grant", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public List<Grant> Grant { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Grant", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Grant
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grantee", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public Grantee Grantee { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Permission", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string Permission { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Grantee", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Grantee
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "URI", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string URI { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayName", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Owner", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Owner
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayName", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: An xml namepspace looks like   abc:xyz where abc is the namespace and xyz is the tag name.  Your xml does not have any namespaces even though the namespace is in the attribute.  So try leaving out the namespace above the classes of make the names space an empty string.

Comment: Hi @jdwent, I tried this, setting ```Namespace = ""``` in each of the XmlRoot and XmlElement items.  Same error.  I also tried by just setting ```Namespace = ""``` above each of the classes, leaving along the class members, and still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` uses the `xsi:type` specifier to resolve the target class for deserialization.

Because your target `class` is named **`Grantee`** you have to decorate it with an `XmlType` attribute specifying the **`CanonicalUser`** as `TypeName`.

```
[XmlType(TypeName= "CanonicalUser")]
public class Grantee
```

Note that you can reduce the `xml namespaces` applied on your classes as shown below.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AccessControlPolicy", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")]
public class AccessControlPolicy
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Owner", IsNullable = true)]
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccessControlList", IsNullable = true)]
    public AccessControlList AccessControlList { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class AccessControlList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grant",  IsNullable = true)]
    public List<Grant> Grant { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Grant
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grantee",  IsNullable = true)]
    public Grantee Grantee { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Permission", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Permission { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[XmlType(TypeName= "CanonicalUser")]
public class Grantee
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID", IsNullable = true)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "URI", IsNullable = true)]
    public string URI { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayName", IsNullable = true)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Owner
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID",  IsNullable = true)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DisplayName", IsNullable = true)]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to use different `xsi:type` specifiers, eg.

```
<Grantee xsi:type="CanonicalUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<Grantee xsi:type="AnotherUser" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

then you have to declare a class for both, having a common base class.

The base class must be decorated with an `XmlIncludeAttribute` for each concrete derived class involved.
The `XmlTypeAttribute` must be applied on the derived classes.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(CanonicalUser))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(AnotherUser))]
public abstract class Grantee
{
    // ...
} 

[XmlType(TypeName= "CanonicalUser", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")]        
public class CanonicalUser : Grantee
{}

[XmlType(TypeName = "AnotherUser", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")]
public class AnotherUser : Grantee
{}
```

Comment: Thanks @pfx, this solved my issue.  Out of curiosity, if there were multiple types of grantees, could I add multiple ```XmlType``` decorations to the one ```Grantee``` class?

Comment: I tried adding multiple ```XmlType``` declarations to the same class, i.e. ```[XmlType(TypeName = "CanonicalUser")]``` followed by ```[XmlType(TypeName = "Group")]```, and even tried putting them in the same line.  In both cases, I get an error in VS stating ```Duplicate `XmlType` attribute``` - do you know a better/more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: @joelc I included the multiple `xsi:type` scenario in my post.

Comment: Hi @pfx just wanted to circle back on this.  Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Rename your class Grant to CanonicalUser.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AccessControlList", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
public class AccessControlList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grant", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public List<CanonicalUser> Grant { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Grant", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
public class CanonicalUser
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Grantee", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public Grantee Grantee { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Permission", Namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; tried that, still getting the same error.  I pasted the exception (same as above) as well as the code showing these changes to the following gist: https://gist.github.com/jchristn/a39a185ebc79afc50c4be2dcdb8a1668

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I tested it, but did not check the posted code and confued Grant and Grantee. Nevertheless the way of @pfx is the better one.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond!  Deleted the gist, no longer relevant.